# SciPy: TypeError when using scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm encountering a vague error when attempting to minimise a function using scipy.optimize.minimize. The error I get is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "general_fd.py", line 103, in <module>:
  a_tmp[index] = minimize(iF.hamiltonian,0,(x,u_last,m_tmp,dt,dx,k*dt,index),tol=1e-3)
   TypeError: float() argument must be a string or number
```

where

```
def hamiltonian(alphas,x_array,u_array,m_array,dt,dx,time,index):
    sigma2 = Sigma_local(time,x_array[index],alphas,m_array[index])**2
    movement = f_global(time,x_array[index],alphas)
    L_var = L_global(time,x_array[index],alphas,m_array[index])
    dx2 = dx**2
    if index==0:
        sigma2R = Sigma_local(time,x_array[index+1],alphas,m_array[index])**2
        tmp = u_array[0]*(abs(movement)/dx - sigma2/dx2) + u_array[1]*(sigma2R/dx2 - abs(movement)/dx) + L_var
    elif index==x_array.size-1:
        sigma2L = Sigma_local(time,x_array[index-1],alphas,m_array[index])**2
        tmp = u_array[-1]*(abs(movement)/dx - sigma2/dx2) + u_array[-2]*(sigma2L/dx2 - abs(movement)/dx) + L_var
    else:
        sigma2L = Sigma_local(time,x_array[index-1],alphas,m_array[index])**2
        sigma2R = Sigma_local(time,x_array[index+1],alphas,m_array[index])**2
        tmp = u_array[index]*(abs(movement)/dx - sigma2/dx2) + u_array[index+1]*(sigma2R/(2*dx2) + min(movement,0)/dx) + u_array[index-1]*(sigma2L/(2*dx2) - max(movement,0)/dx) + L_var
    return tmp[0]

def Sigma_local(time,x,a,m):
    return 0*x
def f_global(time,x_array,a_array):
    return 0.1*a_array*x_array
def L_global(time,x_array,a_array,m_array): #general cost
    return a_array + np.sqrt(x_array) + a_array**2
```

The above code is pretty ugly as I've modified it somewhat in order to try and find the error; my apologies. I've found that minimize-function runs a few trial values of *hamiltonian* before throwing the error message upon the return statement in *hamiltonian*. I've used the minimize function on other, similar functions without this error occurring, and I'm honestly quite stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please always show the full traceback in your question

Comment: Sorry about that, I've put it in now.